# In a paginated MUI DataGrid, how best to position to row on other page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

In a React app I have a paginated MUI DataGrid where I need to programmatically position the DataGrid at a row that might be on another page.  I've looked for a MUI function that performs this task but haven't found one.  The scrollToIndexes method only works for the current page.  According to [scrollToIndexes does not work with pagination](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/6290), an issue filed at GitHub, the only alternative is to "manually change the page" before using scrollToIndexes.

The approach I arrived at assigns a unique ID to a tag in each row.  The ID is the same as the row ID but with an 'm' prepended.  Then I call this routine from a link or a useEffect, depending upon the circumstances:

```js
export const gotoRow = (ID, apiRef, initialTimeout=0) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const rowIndex = gridExpandedSortedRowIdsSelector(apiRef).findIndex((id) => id === ID)
    const pageIndex = Math.floor(rowIndex / ConfigVars.MessagesPerPage)
    setTimeout(() => apiRef.current.setPage(pageIndex)) // Internally the page numbering begins at 0
    setTimeout(() => document.getElementById('m' + ID).scrollIntoView(true), 400)
  }, 200)
}
```

The timeout values were worked out by trial and error.  The setTimeouts are necessary because even though useEffect only fires after rendering, apparently there are still some things going on in the background that DataGrid hasn't completed yet.

For example, if the outer timeout isn't included then "id" in the call to findIndex will be reported as being fetched from an undefined object, which I think means that some object used by gridExpandedSortedRowIdsSelector isn't defined yet.

The approach that I've worked out feels very unreliable, and I'm hoping there's a better way to do this.